# JavaScript & Checkboxes - Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I have 4 tables with about a hundred rows in each table. Each table has its own unique ID (ABC1, ABC2, etc) and each row of each table row has its own unique ID (ABC1-Val1, ABC1-Val2, etc). Each of the rows has its own checkbox (with its own unique name).

I am looking for a piece of JavaScript (possibly working with jQuery) that will work from a button click which, when clicked, the will display only the rows of the tables that have been selected. [Possibly include a remove filtering too].

Thinking out loud - I could use a span with a hidden element toggled between 0 and 1 if the checkbox is unchecked/checked.

Can anyone shed some slight on how to achieve this please?

Comment: Try something like `$('#o1, #o2').find('tr:not(:has(:checkbox:checked))').hide();
$('#o1, #o2').find('tr').has(':checkbox:checked').show();`

Comment: The idea is that you try building it first, post the code here and explain why it failed and if possible provide a jsfiddle to test it. Thinking out loud is good but doesn't get you anywhere unless you try it...Plus people pay more attention to questions that _have code_.

Comment: Try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BdZn3/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/HegPJ/2/

html:

```
<table border="1" id="tableId1">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
<input type="button" value="Filter" id="filterButt"/>
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="resetButt"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#filterButt').click(function(){
    $('#tableId1 tbody').find('tr:not(:has(:checkbox:checked))').hide();
});

$('#resetButt').click(function(){
    $('#tableId1').find('tr').show();
    $('#tableId1 input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: "will display only the rows of the tables that have been selected"
This displays the ones that aren't checked, not the ones checked.

Comment: Thanks, I was in the middle of getting some code together - wasn't expecting replies so quickly!

To get the checked boxes, I just did the inverse 'tr:not(:has(:checkbox:checked))'

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the header on the table when you filter?

Comment: I've updated the answer, again.  I would just use thead and tbody tags.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="filterTablesbtn">Filter</button>
    <button type="button" id="clearFilterbtn">Clear Filter</button>
</div>
ABC1
<table id="ABC1">
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
ABC2
<table id="ABC2">
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
ABC3
<table id="ABC3">
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

window.onload = function()
{
    $('#filterTablesbtn').click(function(){
        filterTable('ABC1');
        filterTable('ABC2');
    });

    $('#clearFilterbtn').click(function(){
        clearFilter('ABC1');
        clearFilter('ABC2');
    });
}

function filterTable(id)
{
    $('#' + id + ' tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked"))
            $(this).hide();
    });
}

function clearFilter(id)
{
    $('#' + id + ' tr').show();
}
```

See the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/pSzk7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I used the answer below in my solution - simply because there is slightly less JS code needed for it!

Comment: @Dustin Cook That's correct, slinky2000's answer is more efficient, I simply posted this around the same time before I saw his answer :)